# show two graphs in on graph

Tags: plotting, graphics

I've plotted graph 1 and graph 2. now I want to show them in one graph in order to compare them with each other, but the command "show" doesn't work. what's the problem and how can I solve it?[image]

Comment: Try to add `PlotRange -> Full` to your `Show`, and see if it helps. In all likelihood, this is because you use two different `ScalingFunctions`

Comment: See the `Possible Issues` section of the documentation for `Show`: "Show uses the options from the first graphic". Consequently, if these aren't what you need, you override these by adding options to `Show`.

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
Show[
  ListPlot[RandomInteger[{10, 100}, {100, 2}], ScalingFunctions -> "Log", PlotStyle -> Red],
  ListPlot[RandomInteger[{10, 100}, {100, 2}], PlotStyle -> Blue]
, PlotRange -> All
]
```

**Reference**

[PlotRange](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html)